# Can't install Spyder after installing Tensorflow and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, spyder

I'm struggling to install Spyder (5.1.5) after installing Keras and Tensorflow.

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

1. Install Anaconda
2. Within Anaconda Navigator create a new environment named 'tensorflow'
3. Install tensorflow and keras within Anaconda Navigator in the 'tensorflow' environment.
4. attempt to install Spyder from Anaconda Navigator in the 'tensorflow' environment. I get the following error message when I do this:

'spyder cannot be installed on this environment. Do you want to install the package in an existing environment or create a new environment?'

The other thing I've tried, from the Anaconda prompt:

1. conda activate tensorflow (activate tensorflow environment)
2. conda install spyder

I get the following error:

Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Better practice is to keep infrastructure and kernels separated. I.e., install one copy of Spyder in a dedicated environment, then use `spyder-kernels` to load different Conda environments as kernels. See [Spyder docs](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#working-with-other-environments-and-python-installations).

Comment: I agree. You can also find more info about that [here](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. From the Anaconda prompt I installed the spyder-kernels. I then opened my existing Spyder installation (from the base environment), and changed the Python Interpreter in 'Preferences' to match the 'tensorflow' environment. I refreshed the console (restarted the kernel). So I think I have followed the instructions as descrbied, yet when I try to execute my code with keras, I still get the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras', so it seems like I'm still missing something.

Answer (score 1):

On command prompt type

```
#Set Up Anaconda Environments
conda create --name tf python=3.8

#Activate the new Environment
source activate tf

#Install Tensorflow
conda install tensorflow

#Install Spyder
conda install spyder

#Launch Spyder
spyder

#Verify installation
import tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the solutions [here](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/found-conflicts-when-installing-spyder-in-an-environment-with-tensorflow-2-5/2718/3) by Ikram and Ashwini resolved my issues. The key fix was that you need to create an environment with Python 3.7, not 3.8.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to install Spyder first in a clean environment and then use pip.

`pip install tensorflow`

which installed tensorflow.keras as well.